# Making BLE Stop Disconnecting after 30 sec on MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, bluetooth-lowenergy, disconnection

We are trying to use a BLE device on our system.

In the application side, we have MvvmCross (for now on Android) with the MvvmCross.Plugin.BLE.
On the slave side, we use a Dialog BLE chip.

After we connect, we are able to send and receive data for 30 seconds, but then the connection is lost, even if it is not idle.

Possible options we tried to explore:

- Is there a KeepAlive mechanism we should use that we're not aware of?
- Is there some kind of Notify procedure we're not implementing?
- Is there a security issue we should implement?
- A null message we should issue?

Any ideas or sample applications would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update (June 21st, 2016)**:

The disconnection happens only after bonding.

If we work in a non bonded connection - it works perfectly for hours.

Comment: Just some food for thought, have you tried other Android devices? Other Android versions? (Tried an iOS device? if applicable). Using any Android-based BLE Diagnostic Apps (BLE ToolBox)? What is being posted in logical (i.e. is the disconnect coming from BluetoothGattServer)?  We had a number of problems with different BLE chipsets and "~30 sec" disconnects and it was related a firmware issue on the Dialog's ARM M0 cpu causes a  com/UART 'glitch', iOS did not care, also some Android APIs and device were fine, some not.

Comment: It was a custom device so firmware changes were possible our side, this is NOT related to MvvmCross at all (we do not use it). Also are you "on-air packet sniffing" to see if the disconnect is coming from the device? Is the device going back to advertising itself after the disconnect (can you auto-reconnect from the droid device, do you have to unpair/repair each time)?

Comment: My colleague is the author of this plugin and we are using it in production. This 30 sec. disconnect isn't normal. We haven't seen this in our projects :( So I would assume, that you really have to go for the suggested sniffer.